# Chamando C pelo R?

Tags: c, r

Como faço para programar em `C` por dentro do `R` ou chamar um código de `C` em `R`?

Já li uns tutoriais, mas não entendi muito bem.

Comment: Geralmente o código C é compilado, então ou você terá uma lib ou um binário executável. Não entendo de R, mas a lógica para usar o C me parece mais essa.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Pelo que eu entendi [desse tutorial](http://users.stat.umn.edu/~geyer/rc/) é bem por aí mesmo. Wagner, você teria algum exemplo de material que consultou e que ainda te deixou com dúvida? Se o link que eu postei for suficiente, posso traduzir e postar como resposta, do contrário favor dizer que aspecto está te trazendo mais dificuldade.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Otimo link. Não sei se estou correto, mas talvez ele não tenha entendido o `dyn.load("foo.so")`, já que `.so` (ou .sl) geralmente é um extensão que indentifica os "equivalentes" das dlls do windows nos sistemas like-unix. Talvez por eles ser usuário windows, não tenha entendido, acho que já da pra formular uma rápida resposta :) Só não o faço pois não conheço R. No caso for Windows seria algo como `dyn.load("foo.dll")`? Vi que existem também em R o metodos `.C`, `.Call`, `.Fortran` e `.External`. -- Se responder já tem o meu +1 garantido

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Infelizmente eu também não conheço R... :( Eu *imagino* - ao ler o link anterior - que o próprio executável do R já se encarrega de compilar o código C para um `.so`, usando as ferramentas já disponíveis no *NIX (gcc, etc). Mas não sei se ele tem a capacidade de fazer isso no Windows, que até onde eu saiba não vem com um compilador C por padrão (necessitando configurações adicionais, que desconheço, por também não ter experiência com R).

Comment: Acho que não, acredito que tenha que compilar previamente, parece que o `.C` serve apenas para chamar uma função. Isto parece uma boa documentação: http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/.C - Mesmo usando QT  (c++ e mingw) no meu caso eu fui tentar usar certa vez o hunspell, achei que o proprio QT compilaria tudo junto, mas nada funcionou, então tive que compilar para uma .lib e passar nos parâmetros do mingw do QT. Mas não tenho certeza @mgibsonbr

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Não estou falando do `.C`, mas do comando `R CMD SHLIB foo.c` (e depois do *include* `dyn.load("foo.so")`). Ele deve fazer a maior parte da "mágica" - num sistema POSIX pelo menos.

Comment: Oi Guilherme, usei o mesmo link que você postou, mas me compliquei nele (rsrs).

Comment: @mgibsonbr eu entendi, não havia me dando conta disto, apensa presumi pela experiencia com outras plataformas, deve ser isto mesmo, talvez ele não tenha configurado o R corretamente no PATH do ambiente.

Comment: @WagnerJorge qual sistema, instalou corretamente o R?

Comment: Instalei no Windows e tá dando o erro: Error 1 occurred building shared library.

Comment: Corrigindo o comentário anterior:

Instalei no Windows, o R está funcionando normalmente (uso basicamente o R faz um tempo já), mas pra colocar código C++ e C tá dando o erro: Error 1 occurred building shared library.

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse pacote: http://www.rcpp.org/
Esse capítulo também é bom: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html